# Why are certain festivals like festivals like - Vishwakarma Puja celebrated according to Gregorian calender i.e every year on 17 September?

Tags: festivals, calendar

Most Hindu festivals are celebrated according to Hindu calender ,so they fall on different date (according to Gregorian Calender) on each year.
Eg - Diwali 2021 was on 4 November 2021 , while Diwali 2022 will be on 24 october 2022.

But Certain festivals like Vishwakarma Puja falls on same date each year i.e.17 september
similarly Makar Sakranti falls on 14 January every year.

Why is like this ?

Comment: I know the reason may be Vishwakarma Puja is celebrated according to solar calender while Diwali according to lunisolar calender. But why is this like this ?

Comment: No Hindu festival can be celebrated on the basis of the Gregorian calender (introduced in 1582 as a modification of the Julian calender, which was in turn introduced in 709, based on the Egyptian solar calendar). Vishwakarma Puja is celebrated on the day of Kanya Sankranti i.e when the Sun enters the zodiac Virgo. Similarly Makar Sankranti means that the Sun enters the zodiac Capricon on that day.

Comment: In the Hindu solar calendar, a day is defined as the time from sunrise to sunset & a month as the time taken for the Sun to migrate from one zodiac to another. While in the lunar calendar, a day is defined as an individual phase in the waxing/waning of the Moon & a month as the time between 2 successive new-moons (Mukhya-chāndra) or full moons (Gauna-chāndra). The Gregorian calendar is a tropical calendar while the Hindu calendars are sidereal ones.